# Firebase+GTM SDK - accessing GA tracker Client ID

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, firebase-analytics

I am implementing v5 Firebase+GTM SDK with the sole purpose of tracking the events in Google Analytics. 
I can't seem to find a way to access GA Client ID (using previous versions of GTM SDK, I was able to access tracker object and get or set the value).
I am talking about this value:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#clientId
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#cid

Is there a way to reach to GA object hidden inside FIRAnalytics?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, I don't think tracker object is surfaced.

What you can do is to generate your own clientID (a simple *guid* would do) and in Google Tag Manager configure a tag to set it as a field. This way you will fully control the cliend id (*&cid*) and therefore change it as you see fit

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible as of today, since Firebase does not expose data via a REST API. There is no API to even pass on the GA client ID.

From GTM's side of things, that is again a closed system since the data from Firebase is intercepted by GTM but cannot be pulled out or tweaked before it is passed to GA.

Comment: Thanks AniV. In the previous version GTM SDK (v3, v4) the _tracker_ object was exposed and we could .get('clientId')

Comment: You can reach out to Firebase Support and file a ticket requesting this feature with a detailed use case. https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/

Comment: I did - no luck :(